# Spring - Bind an interface to an implementation class programmatically

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

In Spring DI, we can bind an interface with an instance programmatically as below:

```
@Bean
public MyService getMyService() {
   return new MyService1();
}
```

Is there a way to bind the interface with MyService1.class instead? I do not want to create the instance myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate your `MyService1` class with `@Service` (or `@Component`, `@Repository` and others...).

This way, when you inject a `MyService` interface, it will automatically look for existing implementations and find `MyService1`.

Note that your Spring configuration must contain component scanning or equivalent.

**NB** : if you have multiple implementations of your interface, you can use `@Qualifier`s.